# Feature request: Relate memberships to Groups and have separate access

Tags: civimember, groups, acl

**Overview**

I have a number of groups. Each group has one or more memberships. With ACL I can discern between the access to the different groups and their contacts. However, when access is granted, the accessor can change all memberships, not only the ones which are related to the group.

**Example use-case**

- Have group Rotterdam and Amsterdam and have
  separate admins for them.
- Add a contact and add them to groups Rotterdam and
  Amsterdam.
- Add a membership.

It is now unclear where the membership belongs
   to and who is allowed to change it.

**Proposed behaviour**

- Click on memberships.
- Add membership.
- Be able to choose and relate the membership from a field populated with the group a contact already belongs to. If left blank (no group selected),fall back to the current behaviour, for compatibility with existing instances.
- Apply ACL to have group admins see and change only their own memberships, depicted by the relationship between the membership and the group.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to say that this is not possible via UI configuration. You will need to setup ACL via civicrm hook([hook_civicrm_aclWhereClause](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_aclWhereClause/)) to grant access for a contact to specific group.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that it is not possible. That is the reason why I prefixed it with feature request. I posted this as a feature request on Github, but was directed to here.